# Process Builder running 2 versions with a time based Create Action?

Tags: workflow, opportunity, visual-workflow, process-builder

I revised the initial process to include few more fields on a time based create action. Now I have 2 records being created the same time and only 1 Process is active. What could be wrong here? Is there a way to reset the Process Builder scheduled Create Action?

Answer (score 0):

Under WorkFlows and Approval > Flows > All scheduled Proccess Builder will be listed. Create a new view add the filter you need see what version of what Process Builder is be used and Start Deleting.